# username availability PDO not working

Tags: php, jquery

This is my HTML Code

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="stfmail" name="staffmail" placeholder="E-Mail" required="required"><span id="result"></span>
```

In jQuery  Ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $("#stfmail").keyup(function()  {       
        var name = $(this).val();   
        if(name.length > 1)
        {       
            $("#result").html('checking...');
            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url  : '../include/check_availability.php',
                data : $(this).serialize(),
                success : function(data)
                          {
                             $("#result").html(data);
                          }
                });
                return false;
        }
        else
        {
            $("#result").html('');
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

PHP

```
if($_POST) 
  {
      $username = $_POST['name'];
      $ob->useravailable($username);
  }




public function useravailable($username)
     {
         $stmt=$this->conn->prepare("select user_name from users where user_name=:uname and delet='0'");
         $stmt->execute(array(':uname'=>$username));
         if($stmt->rowCount()>0)
            {
                echo "<span style='color:brown;'>Sorry username already taken !!!</span>";
            }
        else
            {
                echo "<span style='color:green;'>available</span>";
            }
     }
```

Here i type a username..but in useravailable function only else part is working..
 I type Existing username it works the else part available message is shown.. 
Please help me
thanks

Comment: from where you get this `$ob`? and where you defined `$username`?

Comment: Change `$_POST['name'];` to `$_POST['staffmail'];`

Comment: I'm just wondering why you named the user name field to `user_name` and the deleted one to `delet`? :)

Comment: Thanks Saty....it works

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){    
        $("#stfmail").keyup(function()  {       
            var name = $(this).val();   
            if(name.length > 1)
            {       
                $("#result").html('checking...');
                $.ajax({
                    type : 'POST',
                    url  : '../include/check_availability.php',
                    data : $(this).serialize(),
                    success : function(data)
                              {
                                 $("#result").html(data);
                                 if(data) {                  
                         $(".redbold").html('already this username is there ').show();
                         $("#username").focus();

                    }

                              }
                    });
                    return false;
            }
            else
            {
                $("#result").html('');
            }
        });

    });
    </script>


if($_POST) 
  {
      $username = $_POST['name'];
      $query = mysql_query("SELECT user_name from users where user_name ='".$username ."' ", $con);

                                   while ($row   = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                                   echo $row['user_name '];

                                   }
  }
```

Comment: In that 'redbold' class u have to use css style whatever you want..try this it will work well

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.